# Removing dark borders from UI elements, including windows and buttons

Tags: macos, ui, accessibility

I have somehow managed to configure my Mac to display dark borders around windows, toolbar buttons, and other UI elements, as you can see in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

All apps are now showing borders like this. How can I remove them?

Comment: The look is surprisingly vintage, despite the antialiased rounded corners.

Comment: @Ruslan I'll admit I'm actually fond of this look - I wish modern macOS 10+ supported third-party themes the way that MacOS 8.0 did.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have turned on ‘Increase contrast’ in settings.

Open System Preferences, search for ‘contrast’ and unselect ‘Increase contrast’:

[image]

Comment: Huh. I think I might go turn this **on**